# Update a DIV tag from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm a new developer. I've read a lot of question all around about my topic, and I've seen a lot of interesting answers, but unfortunately, I cannot find a way to resolve mine.
I have a simple form in HTML and `<div id="comment"></div>` in it (empty if there is nothing to pass to the user). This DIV is supposed to give updates to the user, like `Wrong Username or Password!` when it's the case. The form is treated via PHP and MySQL.

```
    ...
    $result = mysqli_query($idConnect, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        mysqli_close($idConnect);
        setCookie("myapp", 1, time()+3600 * 24 * 60); //60 days
        header("Location: ../main.html");
    } else {
        //Please update the DIV tag here!! 
    }
    ...
```

I tried to "read" PHP from jQuery (with AJAX), but whether I didn't have the solution, or it cannot be done that way... I used this in jQuery (`#login` is the name of the form):

```
$("#login").submit(function(e){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data) {
            $("#comment").replaceWith(data);  // You can use .replaceWith or .html depending on the markup you return
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $("#comment").html(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();    //STOP default action
    e.unbind();
});
```

But I'd like to update the DIV tag `#comment` with some message if the credentials are wrong. But I have no clue how to update that DIV, considering PHP is treating the form...

Can you help please ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: so return an error from the server with details in the payload. Read them in the JavaScript

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: When you fix this, the next problem will be that you cannot do a `header` redirect in php when you call your script using ajax. Instead you should send the status back to your script (using json as you need to send data back as well) and do the redirect from javascript.

Comment: Don't forget about the e.preventDefault(); inside your submit function.

Comment: *"Can you help please ?"* - We have and @JayBlanchard posted a good answer/solution for this, so do as he posted to mark this question as solved. *Merci beaucoup*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for AJAX to work, the PHP must `echo` something to be returned from the AJAX call:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        mysqli_close($idConnect);
        setCookie("myapp", 1, time()+3600 * 24 * 60); //60 days
        echo 'good';
    } else {
        //Please update the DIV tag here!!
        echo 'There is a problem with your username or password.'; 
    }
```

But this will not show up in `error: function` because that function is used when AJAX itself is having a problem. This text will be returned in the success callback and so you must update the div there:

```
success:function(data) {
        if('good' == data) {
            // perform redirect
            window.location = "main.html";
        } else {
            // update div
            $("#comment").html(data);
        }
    },
```

In addition, since you're calling the PHP with AJAX, the `header("Location: ../main.html");` will not work. You will need to add `window.location` to your success callback dependent upon the status.

Answer (score 0):

To begin, your pretend is using Ajax to send form data to PHP. So your client (HTML) have to communicate completely via Ajax. After you do authenticate, you need send an "Ajax sign"  to the client.

```
    $result = mysqli_query($idConnect, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        mysqli_close($idConnect);
        setCookie("myapp", 1, time()+3600 * 24 * 60); //60 days
        echo 'true';//it's better for using json format here
        // Your http header to redirect won't work in this situatition 
        // because the process is control by javascript code. Not PHP.
    } else {
        echo "false";//it's better for using json format here
    }
    //the result is either true or false, you can use json to send more details for client used. Example: "{result:'false', message:'wrong username'}";
    // use PHP json_encode(Array(key=>value)) to convert data into JSON format
```

Finally, you have to check the "Ajax sign" in your js code:

```
    $("#login").submit(function(e){
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data) {
            // You can use `data = JSON.parse(data)` if the data format is JSON
            // Now, data.result is available for your checked.
            if (data == 'true')
                  window.location.href = "main.html";
            else 
                  $("#comment").html('some message if the credentials are wrong'); 
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $("#comment").html('Other error you get from XHTTP_REQUEST obj');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();    //STOP default action
    e.unbind();
});
```